# Query regarding Deep learning model performance reporting

Tags: neural-networks, model-evaluation, tensorflow, keras, train

I am working on Human activity recognition via smart device sensors data by using deep learning. However, I am confused to report the results of my deep learning architecture. Therefore, I would like to request that, please guide me in this regard if it is possible. Let me share the detailed step by step:

**1- Dataset description:**

Data is comprised of time-series sensor data and an imbalanced Dataset. The data set contains 12 classes of data and needs prediction human physical activities.

**2- DataSet Distribution**

Suppose we have ten-person data. The distribution of the data sets is as follows:

- 6 for training
- 2 for Validation
- 2 for Testing

**3- According to my knowledge, we Can Monitor the model performance in two ways and take action accordingly in the Human activity Recognition. These two methods are as follows:**

Early Stopping Training
Model Checkpoint

**Early Stopping Training:**

Stop training when a validation metric has stopped improving. I am using TensorFlow Keras. Here is the code for early stopping training:

```
early_Stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode = 'min', patience=10, restore_best_weights=True)
```

I am using 300 epochs, and training typically ends after 20 to 30.

After terminating the training phase, I feed test data data to the model and obtain the result. As per the code line, the model retrieves the best epoch weights (from the validation data) and tests the data (using the test data part) using those weights. I am using only test data set results for reporting.

**Model Checkpoint:**

is a callback to save the model weight during training. So the model or weights can be loaded later to continue the training from the state saved/ or use to test the testing Data.

***Besides that, one other popular way to report the results in deep learning:***

Feed your test data to the model after each epoch during training to obtain performance. Then, after training is complete, choose the best epoch result of the test data.

**Need Advice:**

I'm looking for advice because I'm currently only using Early Stopping Training mechanism. And I'm looking for a Model checkpoint right now. However, the third method is quite popular and seems it will produce better performance values than the Early Stopping Training and Model checkpoint. So, could you please advise me on which technique I should utilize and report on?

Comment: It’s not enough to tell us that the validation typically ends after 20 or 30 bucks. Which optimization rule are you using? Do you have any non-default parameters going into it? Personally I find that (cohen’s) kappa is a better measure of fit for imbalanced categorical data. I don’t know that accuracy is going to tell you the whole story. Do you have regularization or drop out? It looks like you have very small sample sizes, am I misunderstanding that?

Comment: Learning Rate with decay of 0.9 after each 10 epochs -and following is the optimizer tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)

Comment: @EngrStudent yes it is imbalanced data set. For fair comparison, I am using F-score measure.

Comment: How long is it taking to complete a set of 38 epochs of training? If it is taking order of seconds or minutes then you can confirm that your gain schedule is not too aggressive. I’ve been in places were relatively simple things still take 1000 epochs, So I would double check. Adam is pretty good. I like to benchmark it against RMSprop. RMS prop is a decent crowbar. It’s not a surgeons tool, but it tends to be decent against many problems.

Comment: @EngrStudent can I ask about "gain schedule is not too aggressive". Second I am also utilizing RMSprop. But in my case, for 3 data set RMSprop worked well while Adam performed on just 1 data set. Besides this, why we are discussing these things. In the post, I asked about the evaluation method of the deep learning model.

Comment: If you change the learning rate too fast, then it can fail to get to the "orbit" of global maximum before trying to narrow down on a particular geography to call "best".

Comment: @EngrStudent I am following some state-of-the-art research that's why I am changing the learning rate to 0.9 after  10 epochs. However, can you tell me that how should we can identify that my gain schedule is too aggressive?

Comment: I use convergence studies, typically a grid search.  Think of statistical design of experiment applied to (not-finite) mixture models.   So $\alpha x + 1- \alpha y$ over a normalized domain of total epochs.  You can naively grid the normalized domain at 0% to 100% by steps of 20%, so if there is a 1000 epoch budget, the first is 100% A, the last is 100% B, the second is 80% A and 20% B as in 800 steps in A then 20 steps in B.  For ML there is triangle learning rates in PyTorch, but some say big first then small second, when it comes to learning gain schedules.

Comment: @EngrStudent I could not get the complete idea about your above comment. Can you please provide me any Block or material to read in order to get a more solid concept?

Comment: [mixture design from NIST](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pri/section5/pri54.htm); [low-to-high momentum aka high-to-low learning rate](https://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/cs449/momrate.html); [learning rate warmup @ deepai](https://deepai.org/publication/a-loss-curvature-perspective-on-training-instability-in-deep-learning)

Comment: If you make a new question requesting an example of DOE applied to gain schedules in ML, then I could give you a reproducible version with code, and such.  sr

Comment: @EngrStudent Thanks alot. However, I have posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69595923/how-to-decrease-the-learning-rate-every-10-epochs-by-a-factor-of-0-9 problem regarding this since 20 days back. Please check this and verify it. After that, there is still required to post about DOE, gain scheduling then I will do that.

Comment: this is more along the lines of what I was envisioning.  [link] (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/551487/demonstration-of-doe-of-mixture-design-applied-to-2-stage-gain-schedule-for-mach)

Comment: @EngrStudent DO you have knowledge about Cosine Annealing Learning Rate?

Comment: I've read about its likely antecedent n PyTorch and is (afaik) traingular/sawtooth in shape instead of cosine-derived.  the first cycle isn't guaranteed to get two decades lower error untuned to the problem.  Repeated cycles in the figure are just saying the weights orbit the global minimum first found, but there is no guarantee that will be a common case.  the general approach I'm (slowly) engaging should approximately estimate the "cycle period" for the cosine in the first one.  We will see how it goes.